# how to get user input from qdateEdit and select it from database in postgres

Tags: python, postgresql, pyqt5, psycopg2

i want to know how to get the user input in QDateEdit and select it in a table in postgres? here is my code

```
 def date(self):

        try:
            date = self.dateEdit.date()
            print(date)
            conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname="sample", user="postgres", password="admin", host="localhost", port="5432")
            cur = conn.cursor()
            cur.execute("SELECT * FROM data WHERE stdate = '%s'",date)
            result = cur.fetchall()
            self.tableWidget.setRowCount(0)
            for row_number, row_data in enumerate(result):
                self.tableWidget.insertRow(row_number)
                for column_number, data in enumerate(row_data):
                    self.tableWidget.setItem(row_number, column_number, QTableWidgetItem(str(data)))
        except Exception as e:
            print("Error")
```

i am having trouble with this part

```
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM data WHERE stdate = '%s'",date)
```

how do i get the date from QDateEdit and select it in the table in postgres?

and i only want to select the rows where the stdate is equal to the date that the user input in the QDateEdit and display it in the QtableView when i click the select data button
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to:

- Use a datetime.time() not QDate.
- The placeholder is without quotes.

```
dt = self.dateEdit.date().toPyDate()
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM data WHERE stdate = %s", (dt,))
```

Comment: what do you mean by datetime.time()? is that a widget?

Comment: i tried the code but it didn't run the sql query, there is no value showed on the table, do i need to import something to use datetime?

Comment: it printed "Error", the try block did not run so it went to except